# How to downgrade PHP version 5.56 to 5.4 in Ubutu 15.10

Tags: server, php

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I need to install PHP 5.4 version cause of one of PHP plugin just support for php `< 5.56` how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Ondrej oldstable PPA to install php 5.4.  First you need to remove the existing php.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg -l | grep php | grep -w 5.5 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y php5
```